# force https in WebFlow

Tags: apache, grails, https, tomcat7, spring-webflow

I have a grails application deployed on Tomcat7 and exposed by Apache2. The grails application respond on 8080 of the server the standard way but on Apache2 it is served to the user by https://

All works right except for a WebFlow controller. When the webflow redirect the user it change the https:// to http://
How I can force WebFlow to use https:// ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured the Tomcat to be aware of the fact that it is behind an https reverse proxy? You should set `scheme="https"` and `secure="true"` on the `Connector` element in server.xml.

Also make sure your `grails.serverURL` in `Config.groovy` is the full https URL from the clients' point of view.

Comment: scheme="https" and secure="true" is what I'm looking for :) Thank you!

Comment: P.S. I had to add proxyPort="443" too